# Reading generic types from user input

Tags: java, arrays, generics

ive done some research and found nothing, so I need help reading generic types from a user input. Let's say for example I want to enter a integer one case, then when i run the program again, i want to input a string. How would i do that with scanner or another input reader? Heres my code

```
public class array <T,E> {
private T [] a;
private int size;
private int location;
private E add;
private E delete;
private E find;

public array(){

}
public array(int size){
    this.size = size;
    this.location = 0;
    this.a = (T[])(new Object[size]);
}
public boolean add(T element){
    if(location == size){
        return false;
    }else{
        this.a[location++] = element;
        System.out.println("Element added at location " + location);
        return true;
    }
}
public int find(T element){
    for(int i = 0 ; i < location; i ++){
        if(a[i] == element){
            System.out.println("Element found at location " + i);
            return i;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Couldn't find element");
    return -1;
}
public boolean delete(T element){
    int loc = find(element);
    if(loc == -1){
        System.out.println("Couldn't find element");
        return false;
    }else{
    for(int x = loc; x < location - 1; x++){
        a[x] = a[x+1];
    }
        System.out.println("Element deleted");
        location -= 1;
    return true;
    }
}
public void go(){
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(System.in);
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        array a = null;
        int choice = 0;
        System.out.println("Chose what you want to do");
        System.out.println("1: Add a value");
        System.out.println("2: Delete a value");
        System.out.println("3: Find a value and return the index");
        System.out.println("4: Display all elements in array");
        System.out.println("5: Exit");
        System.out.println();
        try{
        choice = scanner.nextInt();
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Incorrect input");
            go();
        }
        switch(choice){
            case 1:
                System.out.println("Enter the element you want to add");
                add = in.read();
                a.add(add);
                break;
            case 2: 
                System.out.println("Enter the element you want to delete");
                delete = in.nextInt();
                a.delete(delete);
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.println("Enter the element you want to find");
                find = in.nextInt();
                a.find(find);
                break;
            case 4:
                System.out.println(a.toString());
                break;
            case 5: 
                System.exit(0);
                break;
        }
        System.out.println("Continue? 1-Yes, 2-No");
        int yn = in.nextInt();
        if(yn == 1){
            go();
        }else{
            System.exit(0);
        }
}
@Override
public String toString(){   
    String string = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < location; i++){
        string = string + " " + a[i];
    }
    return "Numbers " + string;
}
}
```

Heres my main class(Driver)

```
public class ArrayManipulator<T> {

   private static int size;
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    array a = new array();
    System.out.println("Enter the size of the array");
    size = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println("---------------------------");
    a = new array(size);
    a.go();  
 }
}
```

So, my problem is with asking the user to input values for elements in the array in the go() method. I am not such which input reader to use to read generic types, or if that is even possible. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its better to decide what type you enter before creating the object of class array. probably you can get it from user. And after deciding the types, create the object using eg :    `array<Integer,String> arr = new array<Integer,String>`. Or for having a generic type, use   `Object`

Answer (score 1):

Like some people said, you could use `Object` for generic variable type, especially while using generic method or not knowing what data type user would come, like this simple one:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GenericMethod {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Type something that's yours: ");

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        Object thing;
        thing = sc.next();
        isMine(thing);
    }

    // Generic Method
    public static <T> void isMine(T x) {
        System.out.println(x + " is mine.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see you have `new Scanner(System.in)` which indicates you're referring to **textual** user input. The problem here is how would your program know which type should it convert the textual input into?

There's no such thing as "read generic types", you have to convert the input into a proper type (integers, string, your custom class, etc).

One approach here is you ask the user additional info so you can distinguish what kind of input he/she is providing.